# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cd_id' cannot be null in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cd_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `commvendordata` (`new_date`, `cd_id`, `cn_id`, `unit_id`, `vender1`, `vender2`, `vender3`, `vender4`) values (07/17/2021, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?))

how remove this error using laravel

form or blade screenshot

```
<form action="{{route('auth.commvendordata')}}" method="POST" class="shadow-lg p-4 w-f">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="modal-date">
                        <label>Select Date:&emsp;&emsp;</label>
                        <input type="text" name="new_date" placeholder="Select Price Date" class="getdate"/>
                        <button type="button" name="loadform" class="btn btn-warning load-form">Load Form</button>

                    </div>
                  <div class="data" style="display:none;">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
                        <thead class="bg-success">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" class="td-size">CCode</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="td-size">CName</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="td-size">CUnits</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="td-size">Vendor 1</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="td-size">Vendor 2</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="td-size">Vendor 3</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="td-size">Vendor 4</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        
                            <tr id="template">

                                    <td><input type="text" name="ccode[]" class="td-size"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="cname[]" class="td-size"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="cunit[]" class="td-size"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="vendor1[]" class="td-size"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="vendor2[]" class="td-size"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="vendor3[]" class="td-size"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="vendor4[]" id="addrow" class="td-size"></td>
                            </tr>
                        
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" name="commdatasavebtn" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>
                </form>
```

controller screenshot

function commvendordata(Request $request){

```
$cvendordata = new commvendordata;

$new_date = $request->new_date;
$ccode = $request->ccode;
$cname = $request->cname;
$cunit = $request->cunit;
$vender1 = $request->vendor1;
$vender2 = $request->vendor2;
$vender3 = $request->vendor3;
$vender4 = $request->vendor4;
    for($i=0; $i<count($ccode); $i++) {
            $commdata = [
                'new_date'  => $new_date,
                'cd_id'     => $ccode[$i],
                'cn_id'     => $cname[$i],
                'unit_id'   => $cunit[$i],
                'vender1'   => $vender1[$i],
                'vender2'   => $vender2[$i],
                'vender3'   => $vender3[$i],
                'vender4'   => $vender4[$i]
            ];
            DB::table('commvendordata')->insert($commdata);
    }
    Session::put('Success',"Save Data Successfully...!");
    return back();
```

}

database screenshot
[image]

error screenshot
[image]

[image]

form screenshots
[image]

Comment: Update your question with actual code, not screenshots of code

Comment: which code of screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Change your for loop from

```
for($i=0; $i<count($ccode); $i++)
```

To

```
for($i=0; $i<count($ccode)-1; $i++)
```

**Solution 2**

Before

```
DB::table('commvendordata')->insert($commdata);
```

Add this

```
if (trim(implode('', array_values($commdata))) == '') continue;
```

It will skip the row that has all the fields empty(in your case last row).
Also, you should add some validations to ensure users always put some values for fields that are required in the database.

Answer (score 0):

As you are putting blank in last row of the form, the error is coming for that. Put data in your last row, I think the issue will be solved. Also put some validation before inserting row in your db table.

Comment: i insert row dynamic way focus in last cell insert new row always last is empty. how improve my code ignore the last cell

Comment: You need to add add, delete button in last row by using javascript or jquery. Then whenever you don't need  extra row just delete this. There is a lot of code in stackoverflow and other places. Just check that and update that.

Comment: Isn't there a way in Laravel to ignore the empty row when we click on save button?

Comment: i am using array_filter() function but its other error

Comment: "Isn't there a way in Laravel to ignore the empty row when we click on save button? " yes you can ignore it by doing manually as well as before inserting data into database.Hope this will solve the issue.